# Rails - ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get the following error on this code with the create method. Why does the project_id not exist if the build method creates a new Project instance?

> ```
> >      Failure/Error: project.save
> >      
> >      ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
> >        can't write unknown attribute `project_id`
> ```

The error is generated on the save method inside the create action:

```
class CreatesProject 

  attr_accessor :name, :task_string, :project 

  def initialize(name: "", task_string: "") 
    @name = name
    @task_string = task_string 
  end 

  def build
    self.project = Project.new(name: name) 
    project.tasks = convert_string_to_tasks 
    project 
  end 

  def convert_string_to_tasks
    task_string.split("\n").map do |task_string|
      title, size = task_string.split(":") 
      size = 1 if (size.blank? || size.to_i.zero?) 
      Task.new(title: title, size: size.to_i) 
    end
  end 

  def create
    build
    project.save
  end 
end
```

This is the project model associations.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name
  has_many :tasks

 ...methods omitted since it is too long

end
```

This is the task model associations.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :title, :size
  belongs_to :project


....omitted

end
```

This is what the schema in the database looks like for task.

```
  create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "project_id"
    etc....
```

Any ideas what may cause this?

Comment: Check that `project_id` column exists in `tasks` table. You might've forgotten to create it but specified `belongs_to :project` in `Task` model.

Comment: I had both of those things and still get this error.

Comment: Please add Project and Task models code to the question. If they're big then post just the pieces describing associations (`belongs_to`, `has_many`, etc.).

Comment: my test passed when I added project_id to the project table. not sure why this was the solution. could you explain why this worked?

seems nonsensical - to me, this translates to "project belongs_to project"

Comment: This is not correct, `projects` table shouldn't have `project_id` column.

Please add full codes of these two models. You can put them in your GitHub Gist and give links here. The codes in the question are correct, the problem seems to be outside them.

Comment: Here are the codes. I also included the rspec test in case that could be helpful.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/85d2091cc3343aa6bdb5

Comment: It seems that you're using Rails 3. Do you encounter the problem only in tests? Did you try to create project manually in rails console? Try running 'rake db:test:prepare'.